# Intersystems Caché with Java Gateway - Pass parameter as java.io.FileInputStream

Tags: java, intersystems-cache, intersystems, intersystems-ensemble

In my project I'm using a integration of Intersystems Caché with Java by a Java Gateway, it's basically maps JARs and create a class proxies in Caché to access Java classes into the JAR.

A class in Java has a parameter of type FileInputStream , my question is how I should send this parameter Caché proxie ? What type of data in Caché represent the FileInputStream in Java?

Regards,

Lucas Boeing Scarduelli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create proxy for that java, should be created cache-class for FileInputStream too.

simple java class, with FileInputStream as a type for an argument in function

```
package org.daimor;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class test {

    public long sizeStream(FileInputStream stream)
    {
        try {
            return stream.getChannel().size();
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

then I created projection for this jar file in Caché Studio. And wrote a code

```
Set gateway = ##class(%Net.Remote.Gateway).%New()
Do gateway.%Connect("127.0.0.1", 55555)

Set file = ##class(java.io.FileInputStream).%New(gateway, "c:\test.txt")
Set javaObj=##class(org.daimor.test).%New(gateway)
Set size=javaObj.sizeStream(file)
```

so, it works well.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry it's OK.