# Intersystems Caché Java Gateway

Tags: java, intersystems-cache, intersystems, objectscript, intersystems-ensemble

I need some help on development in Caché's Objectscript.

I've been working in this technology for some months and since some days, I'm trying to get the Java Gateway to  work without success. It is supposed to allow me to run java .class et .jar code.
But even if it is explained in the documentation, there is no full example and I'm getting errors over and over. So, I was wondering if someone can provide a full example, correct me or explain what I'm doing wrong?

Here is what I have for now:

My simple java class - write date and time in a file

```
package packagename.packagename2;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class entertest {

    public int enter() throws IOException
    {
         File file = new File("D:\\path\\filemane.txt");

         if (!file.exists()) {
              file.createNewFile();
         }

         BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()));
         bf.write(LocalDateTime.now().toString());
         bf.close();

         return 1;
     }

}
```

My objectscript code - define my gateway and try to call the method

```
Class domain.java.TestJava Extends EnsLib.HL7.Service.TCPService
{

    Method OnProcessInput(pLine As Ens.StringContainer, Output pLineLeftOver As Ens.StringContainer) As %Status
    {
        Do ##super(pLine,pLineLeftOver)
        Set val = 0

        $$$TRACE(val)

        Set gateway = ##class(%Net.Remote.Gateway).%New()
        Do gateway.%Connect("127.0.0.1", 55553)
        Do gateway.%Import("D:\\path\\entertest.jar")

        Set javaObj = ##class(packagename.packagename2.entertest).%New(gateway)
        Set val = javaObj.enter()

        $$$TRACE(val)

        Quit $$$OK
    }
}
```

I get an error :

```
ERREUR <Ens>ErrException: <CLASS DOES NOT EXIST>zOnProcessInput+9^domain.java.TestJava.1 *packagename.packagename2.entertest 
    -- - connecté en tant que '-' numéro - @' Set javaObj = ##class(packagename.packagename2.entertest).%New(gateway)'
```

I used this post but I don't know how he got it working: [Intersystems Caché with Java Gateway - Pass parameter as java.io.FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789169/intersystems-cach%C3%A9-with-java-gateway-pass-parameter-as-java-io-fileinputstream)

I tried to add a service "JavaGatewayService" in the Ensemble production. Did not help...
I also tried to add an object gateway in

System Administration > Configuration > Connectivity > Object Gateways.

Did not help... And I don't know if it should help me...

I'm out of ideas/options.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get a working solution so I'm adding this for sharing it to give a fully step by step guide.

Here is what I needed to do:
In Ensemble: I added a "JavaGateway" service of "EnsLib.JavaGateway.Service" configured with 127.0.0.1 as the address and 55555 as Port (these are default values I think). I also specified using "Java 1.8" in JDKVersion.

I wrote this as Java code and exported it as a Jar archive:

```
package packageName;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class EnterTestClass {

    public long enter() throws IOException {

        File file = new File("D:\\Path\\EnterTestClass.txt");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()));
        bf.write(LocalDateTime.now().toString());
        bf.close();

        return 1;
    }
}
```

In Studio, I created a new class.
Here is the code:

```
Method OnProcessInput(pLine As Ens.StringContainer, Output pLineLeftOver As Ens.StringContainer) As %Status
{
    Set val = 0
    $$$TRACE(val)

    Set gateway = ##class(%Net.Remote.Gateway).%New()
    Do gateway.%Connect("127.0.0.1", 55555)

    Set javaObj = ##class(packageName.EnterTestClass).%New(gateway)
    Set val = javaObj.enter()

    $$$TRACE(val)
    Quit $$$OK   
}
```

And I used the menu "Tools" -> "Extensions" -> "Java Gateway Assistant":
I selected Jar File, gave the full path, the above values 127.0.0.1 and 555555, clicked on "Next", ckecked the class to import and clicked "Finish".

On the right tree of Studio (in namespaces view), the imported class should be visible.

It then worked when launching the OnProcessInput (by sending a tcp request in my case).

Thank you DAiMor for your help with some of my errors and sorry for my english and if the menus don't have exactly the names I wrote (I'm belgian and working on a French version of Studio and Ensemble).

Answer (score 0):

To work with Java in Ensemble, you have to use JavaGateway Service, and you should import Java classes to Caché. You can look at the [documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=EJVG_intro) for more details.
And you can get answer a bit quicker if you ask at the [InterSystems Developer Community portal](http://community.intersystems.com/).

**UPD**:
You tried to do import java classes, but in the wrong way. If you look at the documentation, you will see definition for method `%Import`.

> final method %Import(javaClass As %String, ByRef javaClasses As
>   %ListOfDataTypes, additionalClassPaths As %ListOfDataTypes = "",
>   exclusions As %ListOfDataTypes = "")

As you can see here, the first parameter is javaClass. So, instead of

```
Do gateway.%Import("D:\\path\\entertest.jar")
```

try to import particular java class

```
Do gateway.%Import("packagename.packagename2.entertest")
```

Comment: Do you mean that `Do gateway.%Import("D:\\path\\entertest.jar")` does not import the Java classes? And I already looked several times the documentation page and it did not help. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Sorry, I missed this line. %Import does import Java classes, but by name, not by jar. You should put there one classname from java, or list of classes. Look at the documentation for this class: http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?APP=1&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25Net.Remote.Gateway

Comment: I just tried with `Do gateway.%Import("D:\\path\\entertest.class")` but I receive the same error as above `<CLASS DOES NOT EXIST>` on the line `Set javaObj = ##class(packagename.packagename2.entertest).%New(gateway)`... Do you have another hint?

Comment: I should be able to see "somewhere" some generated proxy classes, right? Can you tell me where they should be placed, in order that I check that also? Thanks.

Comment: Please look at my update of this answer, hope it help.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I understand now what you mean by class. However, I'm still getting the same error. I'm wondering, with this import, how the code can go pick the right java file (.class or .jar file) and get the java code? My ObjectScript code now looks like 
 `Set gateway = ##class(%Net.Remote.Gateway).%New()`
 `Do gateway.%Connect("127.0.0.1", 55555)`
 `Do gateway.%Import("citadelle.EnterTestClass")`
 `Set javaObj = ##class(citadelle.EnterTestClass).%New(gateway)`
 `Set val = javaObj.main()`
 `$$$TRACE(val)`